# when i use the directx library, form screen is not come on c# form application

Tags: c#, directx

when i use the directx library, form screen is not come on c# form application

i have a code like this,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.DirectX;
using Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D;

namespace Creating_A_Basic_DirectX
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Device device;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeDevice();
        }
        private void InitializeDevice()
        {
            PresentParameters presentParams = new PresentParameters();
            presentParams.Windowed = true;
            presentParams.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
            device = new Device(0, DeviceType.Hardware, this, CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, presentParams);
        }
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, Color.DarkSlateBlue, 1.0f, 0);
            device.Present();
        }
    }
}
```

and i was run this code but form screen is not come.
when i was delete directx codes, its run.
i change properties(double click)-->build-->Platform target-->x86

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.DirectX` and `Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D` are legacy Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies. They were created for .NET 1.1 and have been legacy for a very long time. They were last updated in August 2005, are not compatible with .NET 4.x or later, and are only deployed by the legacy DirectSetup package (i.e. they are not included with .NET or any OS).

You should look to use some modern equivalent including [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/), [SlimDX](https://slimdx.org/), or [Unity 3D](https://unity3d.com/).

See [DirectX and .NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/12/09/directx-and-net/)